# Can method overloading be considered a way of describing polymorphism in Java?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, overloading

So, I was studying from **Head First Java** and there I read -

> An overloaded method is just a different method that happens to have the same method name, It has nothing to do with inheritance and polymorphism.

However, I have another famous book named as **Java - The Complete Reference** by Herbert Schildt and in that book, I read:

> Method overloading is one of the ways that Java supports polymorphism. Method overloading supports polymorphism because it is one way that Java implements the “one interface, multiple methods” paradigm.

Which one of them is correct?

Comment: Having several methods in an interface has nothing to do with polymorphism.

Comment: @JBNizet The statements are applied to overloading, not just having several methods

Comment: According to the official sources, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html, method **overriding** is one form of polymorphism

Comment: Both have their perspective. First one is right but second one is not "that" wrong.

Comment: @cricket_007, Yes, I agree with the method overriding part, but my question is related to the overloading and not overriding.

Comment: davidxxx has clearly stated the polymorphic behavior of the method invocation based on the input parameter you pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can method overloading be considered a way of describing polymorphism
>   in Java?

No these are two different concepts.

I think that you incorrectly understood what the author means.

I stressed in bold the important part :

> Method overloading is one of the ways that Java supports polymorphism.
>   **Method overloading supports polymorphism** because it is one way that
>   Java implements the “one interface, multiple methods” paradigm.

It simply means that overloading and polymorphism are not incompatible.

For example, you may have an interface that defines an overloaded method :

```
public interface Doable{
   void doX(String s);
   void doX(Integer s)
}
```

Suppose `MyDoable` an implementation of it and `MyChildDoable` a subclass of `MyDoable`.

When you write :

```
MyDoable myDoable = new MyChildDoable(); 
myDoable.doX("a")
```

the compiler will bound the invoked method to  `void doX(String s);` (**overloading**) but at runtime, the method of the instance (`MyChildDoable`) will be used (**polymorshism**).

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question in the title, no, you cannot use method overloading to describe polymorphism.

Method Overloading is when a class has two or more methods by the same name, the only difference is its parameters.  This is a completely difference concept than polymporhism.

Polymorphism is the ability of an object to take on many forms. This occurs when a parent class reference is used to refer to a child class object.

For example,  if I was tasked with creating some type of application for a zoo and I wanted to keep track of the animals using classes.  I would make a class called "Animal" and additional classes for each animal, "Lion", "Eagle", "Dolphin". After declaring the animal classes as subclasses, I can then use the concept of polymorphism to create Lions, Eagles, and Dolphins which are of type "Animal".

Comment: I too agree with your answer but I was wondering why so many people follow The Complete Reference despite the fact that it has written a blunder in this concept.

Comment: Polymorphism applies to classes and methods. Simply having subclasses is not polymorphism, but just OOP

Comment: I think you are thinking to far ahead.  The Complete Reference does not say that Method Overloading is way of describing polymorphism, it just simply states that method overloading supports polymorphism.  I don't have the page in the book in front of me so I cant really give a full opinion but it seems like it is talking about overloading constructors methods and then depending on your situation using those methods to use the polymorphism concept.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is not of one type, there are different types of polymorphism. Please refer this wonderful link - [Java Polymorphism](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-polymorphism/) to understand it better.

Overloading supports polymorphism, the polymorphic behavior invocation is based on type arguments passed and it takes place in an ad-hoc way.

Answer (score 0):

So, there is this idea of compile time polymorphism and runtime polymorphism. The idea of polymorphism implies same interface but different implementations.

The way "compile time" polymorphism works is through function overloading i.e. you have the same function name but with different arrity. I am guessing this is what the second second book is referring to as "polymorphism supported through method overloading". However, strictly speaking the interface also includes the arrity, which means method overloading might not constitute polymorphism.

Runtime polymorphism is where the actual type of a given object is what dictates what implementation should be used. This is where the interface / base class and derived class comes into picture. This would be the more accurate definition of polymorphism - at least from an object orientation point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding - this is about polymorphism.

```
public class Base {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("base");
    }
}

public class Extend extends Base {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Extend");
    }
}
```

Let's look at the output

```
new Base().print();
```

will print "Base"

```
new Extend().print();
```

will print "Extend".

Overloading - this is about method overload in one class with different parameters:

```
public class ABC {
    // method 1
    void method(int a){
        System.out.println("method 1");
    }

    // method 2
    void method(int a, int b){
        System.out.println("method 2");
    }
}
```

Let's look at the output

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
abc.method(5);
```

will invoke method(int) and print "method 1"

```
abc.method(1,2)
```

will invoke method(int, int) and print "method 2"

Overriding - this is runtime feature;

Overloading - this compile time feature;
all overloading method (with one name) must be same return type or void.